# Ansible can be run successfully with wrong pass second time if the first time successful

Tags: ansible

My playbook:

```
-hosts: devops

  tasks:
    - name: Test Connection
      ping:
      register: res

    - name: Print the pint result
      debug:
         msg: "{{ res }}"
```

My inventory:

```
[devops]
 XX.XX.XX.XX ansible_user=userName ansible_ssh_pass=userPass
```

First time, I ran the Ansible playbook with the right SSH password, and the playbook can be run successfully. Then I ran the playbook with a wrong ssh password in a short time, the playbook can run successfully thought the SSH password is wrong. But after a while, with the same wrong password, the playbook cannot be run successfully.
So my question is that whether there is something like cache or session with Ansible playbook? If yes, how can I resolve this issue?

The version of my Ansible is 2.4.3.

Comment: [Yes, there is.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args) What is the issue?

Comment: For the second run, I need the result to be failed, not successful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> For the second run, I need the result to be failed, not successful.

Remove or set a different value in [`ssh_args` option in `ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args).

Remember that removing it completely will cause Ansible playbooks to run significantly slower.